# How can I convert HTML to string for PDF generation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, blazor, syncfusion

I want to convert my HTML DOM element to a string so that I can use it for Pdf generation.

I tried the following code in JavaScript but it returns an HTML element.

```js
    function getHtmlString() {
        var element=document.getElementById("pdfdiv"); 
        var str = element.innerHTML;
        console.log(str);
        return str;
    };
```

```html
<div id="pdfdiv">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--<h3  style="margin-left:150px;"><strong> Patient Details</strong></h3>-->

        <table width="100%" style="padding:0px 105px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="float:left" width="75%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       "Hi" @order.Id
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h2><strong> Patient Order</strong></h2>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</div>
```

This returns the following:

```
<!--!-->
<html><!--!-->
<!--!-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

<body><!--!-->


    <table width="100%" style="padding:0px 105px"><!--!-->
        <!--!--><thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><!--!-->
            <tr><!--!-->
                <td><!--!-->
                    <table style="float:left" width="75%"><!--!-->
                        <!--!--><thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody><!--!-->
                            <tr><!--!-->
                                <td><!--!-->
                                   "Hi" 4<!--!-->
                                </td><!--!-->
                                <!--!--><td>
                                    <h2><strong> Patient Order</strong></h2>
                                </td>

                            </tr><!--!-->
                        </tbody><!--!-->
                    </table><!--!-->
                </td><!--!-->
            </tr><!--!-->
        </tbody><!--!-->
    </table><!--!-->
</body><!--!-->
```

Due to this, I can't covert to PDF by passing this string to `PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert(htmlstring);`. It throws an exception of `Error: Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfException: Html conversion failed`. How can I convert the HTML DOM element to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported exception in the HTML converter may occur due to converting HTML string in a URL conversion method. The convert method with a single argument is for URL to PDF conversion. Kindly refer to the below code snippet for converting HTML string to PDF. Kindly try the conversion with the below code snippet and let us know the result.

```
//Convert HTML string to PDF  
PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert(htmlText, baseUrl);
```

Please refer below links for more information,

**UG**: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit#html-string-to-pdf

**KB**: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9890/how-to-convert-html-string-to-pdf-using-c-and-net

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8174/how-to-preserve-resources-during-html-string-to-pdf-conversion

**Note** : I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank you gowtham for sharing this link.Actually My html string was wrong so that's why exception is getting.Now I convert my razor view using View engine and ViewContext so this returns me expected Html string.And using Syncfusion.HtmlToPdfConverter.QtWebKit.Net.Core it's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the way that your JavaScript is set up, your code actually *is* returning a string.

Seen here:

```js
var element=document.getElementById("pdfdiv"); 
var str = element.innerHTML;

console.log(str)
console.log("The variable type is...")
console.log(typeof(str))
```

```html
<div id="pdfdiv">Make me into a string, please!</div>
```

The solution most likely lies in the library you appear to be using: [Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/converting-html-to-pdf). According to the documentation, the `Convert()` function takes a URL as a parameter, not an HTML string. This is what's leading the program throwing an error.

I'd recommend listing all the libraries you're using in your code for future questions asked on StackOverflow.